# How to center many buttons in flexible div?

Tags: html, css

I have alphabet links under the header. Div and link are flexible, link are close to each other at the same distance(0px). How to center link in this div?

HTML:

```
<div class="alph">
    <a href="/alphabet/a/">A</a>
    <a href="/alphabet/b/">B</a>
    <a href="/alphabet/c/">C</a>
    ...  
</div>
```

Comment: `.alph a {text-align:center;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you haven't changed any display properties for the anchors, setting `text-align: center` on the containing `div` will center them.

```
.alph {text-align: center;}
```